# TypeError: this.props.ajouterRecette is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

****i'm new in React, and i have this message of errors, i follow a tutoriel and a made the same things, but in my code it dosen't work, why ?**

**the file App.js****

```
import React, { Component } from 'react' // CSS import './App.css' import Header from './components/Header' import Admin from './components/Admin' import Card from './components/Card' import recettes from './recettes'

//firebase import base from './base'

class App extends Component {   state = {
    pseudo: this.props.match.params.pseudo,
    recettes: {}   }  

  componentDidMount() {
    this.ref = base.syncState(`/${this.state.pseudo}/recettes`, {
      context: this,
      state: 'recettes'

    })   }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    base.removeBinding(this.ref)   }


  ajouterRecette = recette => {
    const recettes = { ... this.state.recettes}
    recettes[`recette-${Date.now()}`] = recette
    this.setState({recettes})
       }

  chargerExemple = () => this.setState({recettes})

  render () {
   ...
    )   } }

export default App
```

**the file AjouterRecette.js**

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react'

    class AjouterRecette extends Component {   state = {
        nom: '',
        image: '',
        ingredients: '',
        instructions: ''   }


      handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault()
        const recette = { ...this.state }
        this.props.ajouterRecette(recette)
        // Reset
        Object.keys(recette).forEach(item => {
          recette[item] = ''
        })
        this.setState({ ...recette })   }

      render () {
        return (
          <div className='card'>
            <form className='admin-form ajouter-recette' onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>

            </form>
          </div>
        )   } }

    export default AjouterRecette
```

I want to fix this error please

TypeError: this.props.ajouterRecette is not a function

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question code properly and let us know what tutorial you are using?

Comment: @dannybee i added a screenshot :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `ajouterRecette` as a props down to your `AjouterRecette` component, like this:

```
render() {
  <AjouterRecette ajouterRecette={this.ajouterRecette} />
}
```